# Why does Python call __str__ instead of returning long value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple class that extends long to accept a string with value modifiers (ie '10m' would be 1024*1024*10)

I have the `__str__` function that prints the original value passed in (ie if '10m' is passed in, return '10m')

Problem is that when I call something such as:

```
>>>  printf("%d" % Size('10m'))
```

I get the following

```
SystemError: ../Objects/stringobject.c:4044: bad argument to internal function
```

Obviously if I print `"%s"` I get '10m'

So the question is, since I'm subclassing long, why does the class call `__str__` when it should be getting the long value.

BTW, a bit more testing shows that the `%x` and `%f` will print the integer value which confuses me more.  I also tried adding the `__format__` but that appears to only be called on when `"...".format()` is called.

EDIT #1, Here's the code:

```
class Size(long):
    '''Represents a size reflected bytes.  Subclass of long.
     Size passed in must be in the formats <int> or "0x<int>" or "0x<int><unit>" or "<int><unit>" or "<int><unit><int><unit>....".
     "0x<int><unit>0x<int><unit>" or similar numbers are not supported as is "<int><unit><int>"

    b = bytes
    s = sectors (512-byte)
    k = kilobytes
    m = megabytes
    g = gigabytes
    t = terabytes
    '''

    units = { 'b':1, 's':512, 'k':1024, 'm':1024 ** 2, 'g':1024 ** 3, 't':1024 ** 4 }

    def __new__(cls, value):
        '''Creates a Size object with the specified value.

        Value can be a number or a string (optionally prefixed with '0x' or
        postfixed with a type character).  If using hex, the final character
        will be treated as part of the value if it is a hex digit, regardless
        of whether it is a valid unit character.

        Examples:
           Size(50)
           Size("0x100s") # 256 sectors
           Size("64")
           Size("512k")
           Size("0x1b") # this is 1b bytes, not 1 byte
        '''
        self = _new_unit_number(value, cls.units, long, cls)
        return self

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._orig_value = value

    def __str__(self):
        print "calling str"
        return str(self._orig_value)  # Convert to str in case the object was created w/an int

    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        print "calling format"
        print format_spec
        try:
            value = format(str(self), format_spec)
        except ValueError:
            value = format(int(self), format_spec)
        return value

def _new_unit_number(value, unit_list, num_type, cls):
    '''Converts a string of numbers followed by a unit character to the
    requested numeric type (int or long for example).
    '''
    base = 10
    start = 0
    digits = string.digits
    try:
        if value[0:2] == '0x':
            start = 2
            base = 16
            digits = string.hexdigits

        if value[-1] in digits:
            return num_type.__new__(cls, value[start:], base)
        else:
            try:
                # Use a regex to split the parts of the unit
                regex_string = '(\d+[%s])' % (''.join(unit_list.keys()))
                parts = [x for x in re.split(regex_string, value[start:]) if x]

                if len(parts) == 1:
                    return num_type.__new__(cls, num_type(value[start:-1], base) * unit_list[value[-1]])
                else:
                    # Total up each part
                    # There's probably a better way to do this.
                    # This converts each unit to its base type, stores it in total,
                    # only to be converted back to the base type. 
                    total = 0
                    for part in parts:
                        total += num_type(part[start:-1], base) * unit_list[part[-1]]

                    # Finally return the requested unit
                    return num_type.__new__(cls, total)
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError("Invalid %s unit identifier: %s"
                    % (cls.__name__, unit_list[value[-1]]))

    # not a string or empty, see if we can still use the class's constructor
    except (TypeError, IndexError):
        return num_type.__new__(cls, value)
```

Comment: How is `Size` defined?

Comment: Note that "m" is the international symbol for meter, or the prefix for 10^-3.  If you want 10^6, use M.  If you want 2^20, use Mi.

Comment: Where are you getting a `printf()` function from in Python 2.7?

Comment: I assume your are overriding `__new__`?

Comment: Tried implementing __int__ method and it seems to ignore it.  Also tried __long__ method for giggles... same behavior

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment.

I find this question highly interesting. I tried to replicate the behaviour using this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

class Size (long):
    def __new__ (cls, arg):
        if arg and type (arg) == str:
            if arg [-1] == 'm':
                return super (Size, cls).__new__ (cls, long (arg [:-1] ) * 2 ** 20)
        return super (Size, cls).__new__ (cls, arg)

    def __init__ (self, arg):
        self.s = arg

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.s

a = Size ('12m')
print (a)
print ('%s' % a)
#The following fails horribly
print ('%d' % a)
```

Behaviour as described by OP. But now comes the funny part: When I inherit from int and not from long, it works smoothly:

```
class Size (int):
    def __new__ (cls, arg):
        if arg and type (arg) == str:
            if arg [-1] == 'm':
                return super (Size, cls).__new__ (cls, int (arg [:-1] ) * 2 ** 20)
        return super (Size, cls).__new__ (cls, arg)

    def __init__ (self, arg):
        self.s = arg

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.s
```

That is, it works fine in python2, but fails in python3. Strange, strange.

Comment: You basically have the class that I've written (mine just supports more modifiers like K, m, g, etc) and thats the exact problem.  Interesting that it fails on long but not on int....  I need long since we go beyond the 32bits that int supports.

Answer (score 2):

Please see Python issue tracker, [Issue 18780: SystemError when formatting int subclass](http://bugs.python.org/issue18780):

```
>>> class I(int):
...   def __str__(self):
...       return 'spam'
...
>>> '%d' % I(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: Objects/unicodeobject.c:13305: bad argument to internal function
```

This works in 3.4.0alpha4, but not in 3.[0123].

Comment: note: the code works on Python 2.7 (for `int` subclass). It breaks for `long` subclass.